# difference between two linked lists, O(N)

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list, big-o, pseudocode

I have two linked lists with unique but with the same elements in shuffled order.

Then random element gets deleted from list1. How can I determine deleted element?

Example:

> list1 **0 3 7 8 1**
>
> list2 **3 7 8 1 0**

..deleting..

> list1 **- 3 7 8 1**
>
> list2 **3 7 8 1 0**

Answer: **0**

The most important part is that I need to do it by **O(N).**

Comment: Try some code. See how it works. If doesn't work, come back with some relevant questions.

Comment: @r-sahu I know how to do it in two steps, but it will be not O(N). This problem is easy, but I need only O(N)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the lists just contain numbers (as in your example), you can take the difference of their sums:

```
sum(list2) - sum(list1)
```

Comment: To make it even more effective just sum differences btw elements in each list. That will save one variable :)

Comment: Yes! Why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Stuff the elements from list 1 into a hash set.  Try to stuff each element from list 2 into the same hash set.  If it goes in, that's your element.

Comment: Sure it is.  Explain to me how it could possibly not be, considering the insert into a hash set is `O(1)`

Comment: Worst case, each insertion is O(n), for a full O(n²) upper bound.

Comment: Yeah, I see where you're going.

Comment: @TrippKinetics since when hash set guaranties O(1) perfomance?

Comment: @Slava: Tripp probably meant the O(1) amortized expected performance.

Comment: @Deduplicator Indeed.

Comment: @Deduplicator How about allocating an expected size for the hash set that is the size of the larger of the two lists?  Very memory-inefficient, but O(n), no?

Comment: @TrippKinetics: No, you might still be unlucky.